# Systematic List Indexing in R

Tags: r

I've to extract `F Value` from a list of ANOVA Tables.

```
tear <- c(6.5, 6.2, 5.8, 6.5, 6.5, 6.9, 7.2, 6.9, 6.1, 6.3,
      6.7, 6.6, 7.2, 7.1, 6.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6)
gloss <- c(9.5, 9.9, 9.6, 9.6, 9.2, 9.1, 10.0, 9.9, 9.5, 9.4,
       9.1, 9.3, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 9.2, 8.8, 9.7, 10.1, 9.2)
opacity <- c(4.4, 6.4, 3.0, 4.1, 0.8, 5.7, 2.0, 3.9, 1.9, 5.7,
         2.8, 4.1, 3.8, 1.6, 3.4, 8.4, 5.2, 6.9, 2.7, 1.9)
Y <- cbind(tear, gloss, opacity)
rate <- factor(gl(2,10), labels=c("Low", "High"))
additive <- factor(gl(2, 5, length=20), labels=c("Low", "High"))

fit <- manova(Y ~ rate * additive)
summary.aov(fit)
```

I can accomplish the task by using the following code:

```
summary.aov(fit)[[1]][-4,4]
summary.aov(fit)[[2]][-4,4]
summary.aov(fit)[[3]][-4,4]
```

I wonder if there is a way like this

```
summary.aov(fit)[[1:3]][-4,4]
```

to complete the task in more elegant way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sapply` across a list consisting of a numeric vector, i.e. `1:3`.

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) summary.aov(fit)[[i]][-4,4])
             [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 15.786848073 7.917808 0.1036289
[2,]  6.897959184 3.729072 1.2076890
[3,]  0.004535147 3.315068 0.9760335
```

---

You can also access the variable directly, by using `sapply` over `summary.aov` which is a list.  The F-Value is a named element `F value` - this contains a space, so to index it you have to wrap it in backticks:

```
sapply(summary.aov(fit), function(x) x$`F value`)

      Response tear  Response gloss  Response opacity
[1,]   15.786848073        7.917808         0.1036289
[2,]    6.897959184        3.729072         1.2076890
[3,]    0.004535147        3.315068         0.9760335
[4,]             NA              NA                NA
```

Comment: @MYaseen208 Answer edited to illustrate how to access the F-value directly.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of task, the `*apply` family of functions is your friend:

```
sapply(summary.aov(fit), "[", -4, 4)
```

It is not immediately obvious, but "[" is the function that is really behind using [] in R (and its first parameter is the object you want to subset - see `?"["`), the other parameters are passed to this function as well.
As an alternative that doesn't require this knowledge:

```
sapply(summary.aov(fit), function(cursummary){cursummary[-4,4]})
```